# Thread or Separate Object instances?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

My rule of thumb about using thread is: if multiple instances of the same object needs to run concurrently, use threads. But I am facing the design choice issue in a scenario similar to the one I am describing below. Please help me clarify this once and for all:

---

> (Reusing the example from my previous
>   post)   
>  I have 5 Pen object instances,
>   100 Author threads, and 3 Paper object
>   instances.   
> Any number of Authors may
>   be using any number of Pens to write
>   on any given paper.   
> I have created
>   blocking queue to protect the Pen
>   objects being accessed by Authors.
>   If all pens in the queue are used,
>   Authors wait.   
> The Pen instances take
>   data from Author threads and append it
>   to the (specified) Paper instance.
>   After updating Paper instance, Pen
>   also updates the invoking Author
>   thread.

Questions:

- Is there value in running the Pen
  object as threads?
- If so, how would I pass data from
  **Author thread to Pen thread** so that
  the Pen thread can execute the **read**
  (from author), **write** (to Paper), and
  **write back** (back to invoking Author
  thread) safely?

Comment: Threads are *only* way to make code execute in parallel.

Comment: You may find using one thread is simpler and faster.  Why are you using multiple threads? Is this homework?

Comment: @PeterLawrey This is a hypothetical scenario, not a homework (or might as well be one :) But I guess I am using threads for Author to model its 'concurrent' nature. What do you mean when you say one thread is simpler and faster?

Comment: Often these sort of tasks can be implemented in one thread with say a loop (simpler) and it ends up being faster than using multiple threads because the overhead is greater than the gain you might achieve. Alot depends on exactly how much independant work each author is doing.  If its not doing much you may find less threads get better performance removing most/all the advantage of using multiple threads. Without more details I would assume the optimal number of threads is 1.

Comment: With one thread, there is no need for synchronization, blocking queues, locks (simpler) and data is into top level cache and doesn't need to distributed to other core's caches. (faster) It may be than multiple threads help (esp if each author has to think for a while about what to write before writing it), otherwise given you have only three pieces of paper, it is likely you won't get more than 3x improvement using multiple threads, but you can easily lose this much performance in overhead.

Comment: @PeterLawry Thanks for the detailed explanation. Authors are executing the same tasks with different data. So, each of them are unique (?). But, say, if the Authors are randomly deciding to write on some paper and that a given Author may return to write again at a random time, would it be ok then to store all 100 of initial Authors is a list and then pull them out at random and start it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first take would be that Authors are *workers* (i.e. possibly threads), while pen and paper are *resources* (i.e. no threads - only *used by* some workers).

I would refactor the design to move the functionality from Pens to Authors. Also I would try to model Authors as [`Callable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)s (or [`Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)s if there is no need to return any result) instead of threads, and run them within the [`Executor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) framework - this gives higher level abstractions to work with, resulting in cleaner and safer code.

Comment: @PeterTorok Thank you for the comment. If I move the functionality from Pens to Author, the Pen entity becomes useless in this scenario. Intuitively (or if I wanted to model the scenario literally) doesn't it make sense to have the Pen object thought?

Comment: @Tom, according to your description, Pen is a *scarce resource* whose absence prevents most of the Authors from working at any given point in time. So you could view it as a sort of token which allows Authors to do their job.

Comment: You are correct with regards to _scarce resource_. But, does that mean Pen would be a semaphore within the Authors object that each Author would then try to acquire?

Comment: @Tom, hmmmm, indeed it could be a semaphore too. This also depends on your domain model - whether Pen is internal to the Authors or is seen (and used?) by the external world.

Comment: @Peter But wouldnt it make a better model to keep pen as a separate object if we, say, also have to introduce later an owner of the pen(s) which the authors borrow? Something of a [Library study room](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) model?

Comment: @Tom, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Peter In that case is it still advisable to move the functionality from Pens to Authors? Pens should do what they do.. :s